# Signing mails sent through SMTP with DKIM

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, dkim

I have setup DKIM in my google apps for mail signing, when sending mails through GMail interface it signs the mail but when I send a mail through my webserver using SMTP (from CodeIgniter) it doesnt signs the mail.

Can anybody help me what should I do?

Comment: Sorry, off-topic. You should ask this on ServerFault, StackOverflow is for programming-related questions. The guys on ServerFault should be better able to answer your question.

Comment: I dont think its offtopic because I believe we can sign through headers of mail, without the need to set anything on server. Still my belief, after reading mail headers I think so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's actually a server configuration thing. But since you posted on SO, there is also a way to sign the mails manually from within PHP. http://php-dkim.sourceforge.net/

Also had been covered before here: [Setting up DomainKeys/DKIM in a PHP-based SMTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799611/setting-up-domainkeys-dkim-in-a-php-based-smtp-client)

Answer (score 4):

I create new project in googlecode. the name was [phpMailDomainSigner](http://code.google.com/p/php-mail-domain-signer/)
It support DKIM-Signature and DomainKey-Signature in Object Oriented Style.

**Here some example:**

```
// Create mailDomainSigner Object
include_once './lib/class.mailDomainSigner.php';

$mds = &new mailDomainSigner($domain_priv,$domain_d,$domain_s);
$new_data = $mds->sign(
                $mail_data,
                "Message-ID:Subject:From:Content-Type:MIME-Version:Content-Transfer-Encoding:Received:To:Date",
                true,true,false);
```

Comment: What is the contents of `$mail_data` ?