# Using Google App to Email from Domain

Tags: php, html, email

So I linked the google app to my website. I need to use it to send people emails when they need to recover a password. I'm not exactly sure how this google apps thing works. But how do I send users that request password recovery an email from the google account with the information. What I'm asking is how do I write a php email script that uses the google mail account? I know I can write something like this:

```
<?php
 $to = "recipient@example.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
```

But how do I send that automatically from my google account.

Comment: "I'm not exactly sure how this google apps thing works" - then why are you using it? Your question isn't clear.

Comment: @Paul because I'm trying to setup an email server where I can talk to registered users by sending them information such as their password.

Comment: You want to send them their Google password?

Answer (score 0):

Search for DKIM (DomainKeys Identified Mail);

-> Setup your google apps

-> use dkim library

This links will help you :

1. [DKIM](http://php-dkim.sourceforge.net/)
2. [DKIM Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799611/setting-up-domainkeys-dkim-in-a-php-based-smtp-client)
3. Implemented [Here](http://technew.in/) (Check the registrartion email)