# Sign manually a message with DKIM

Tags: email, smtp, dkim, smtp-auth

I've a problem with dkik.

I send message signed by dkim but my mail server doesn't support this feature.
So I've generate a pair of keys (private and public) and I've configured the TXT record with the public key.

The problem is that I haven't access to the mail server.
Can I sign the message manually with my client mail or in other way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a thread that includes some options for client-side DKIM signing - [Setting up DomainKeys/DKIM in a PHP-based SMTP client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2799611/setting-up-domainkeys-dkim-in-a-php-based-smtp-client) .

That said, most mail servers support DKIM out of the box at this point - you may want to switch to one that does.